# Помогите разобрать правильность написаного

Tags: языкознание

правильно ли написанно "съ нами богь"

Comment: По крайней мере одна ошибка есть — в слове "написанно". О, вполне три: начало со строчной и без вопросительного знака. Или даже четыре! Впрочем, все пять.

Comment: Главное, "написаного", но "написанно". Да, тут трудно что-либо разобрать.

Answer (score 1):

Нет. В слове Богъ - во-первых, ЕР (твердый знак), во-вторых - заглавная буква.
Остальное - см. у Hermit'а